# bash variable whose value changes dynamically?

Tags: bash

I'm a bash newb; just curious if this is possible...

assume i have ~/.bash_profile (mac terminal) w/ following declarations:

```
export src=~/Developer/src
export myapp=$src/myapp

alias buildapp='build $myapp' # just an example...
```

this gets loaded when i start up the terminal, and everything's fine.

what i want to do is, later when i switch to a different branch/depot/whatever, i want to type,

```
export src=~/Developer/temp_src
```

in the shell, and make $myapp automatically reference the new $src variable...

is this actually possible?

Comment: The simple answer is that this isn't possible with variables. They don't remember the expression used to assign them, and can't re-evaluate it dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create `myapp` variable and just use this alias:

```
alias buildapp='build "$src/myapp"'
```

Having said that, it is usually better to use a function instead of `alias`:

```
buildapp() { build "$src/myapp"; }
```

Comment: i thought of that, but hoped to avoid it because...

i have 4-5 different variables all depending on $src, and each of them is fairly long (20-30 chars; e.g. $src/foo/bar/baz/whararara/....); and then i have bunch of aliases that reference any of those 4-5...

Comment: If possible, you can put all variable assignments based on `$src` inside this function.